# VBA: Extract page title via HttpRequest

Tags: excel, vba

I usually use the below code to scrape website.

```
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = HttpReq.responseText
```

With this code, "html.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innerText" returns empty string. Is there any way to get page title using DOM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the page source?

Comment: For example, https://www.amazon.com